# MLFLOW on Databricks - Cannot log a Keras model as a mlflow.pyfunc model. Get TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, mlflow

Hi all: this is one of my first posts on Stackoverflow - so apologies in advance if i'm not conforming to certain standards!

I'm having trouble saving my Keras model as a `mlflow.pyfunc` model as it's giving me a "cannot pickle a 'weakref' object when I try to log it.

**So why am i saving my Keras model as a pyfunc model object in the first place? This is because I want to override the default predict method and output something custom**. I also want to do some pre-processing steps on the X_test or new data by encoding it with a tf.keras.StringLookup and then invert it back to get the original categorical variable class. For this reason, I was advised by Databricks that the mlflow.pyfunc flavor is the best way to go for these types of use-cases

The Keras model works just fine and i'm able to log it using `mlflow.keras.log_model`. But it fails when i try to wrap it inside a cutomer "KerasWrapper" class.

Here are some snippets of my code. For the purpose of debugging, the current `predict` method in the custom class is just the default. I simplified it to help debug, but obviously I haven't been able to resolve it.

I would be extremely grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

**ALL CODE ON AZURE DATABRICKS**

**Custom mlflow.pyfunc class**

```
class KerasWrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
  
  def __init__(self, keras_model, labelEncoder, labelDecoder, n):         
    self.keras_model = keras_model
    self.labelEncoder = labelEncoder
    self.labelDecoder = labelDecoder
    self.topn = n
    
  def load_context(self, context): 
    self.keras_model = mlflow.keras.load_model(model_uri=context.artifacts[self.keras_model], compile=False)
  
  def predict(self, context, input_data):
    scores = self.keras_model.predict(input_data)
    return scores
```

**My Keras Deep Learning Model** (this works fine by the way)

```
def build_model(vocab_size, steps, drop_embed, n_dim, encoder, modelType):
  
  model = None

  i = Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64")
  
  #embedding layer
  e = Embedding(vocab_size, 16)(i)
  s = SpatialDropout1D(drop_embed)(e)

  x = Conv1D(256, steps, activation='relu')(s)
  x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
  x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

  #output layer
  x = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)

  model = Model(i, x)
  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()
  
  return model
```

**MLFLOW Section**

```
with mlflow.start_run(run_name=runName):

  mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()   

  #Build the model, compile and train on the training set
  #signature: build_model(vocab_size, steps, drop_embed, n_dim, encoder, modelType):
  keras_model = build_model((vocab_size + 1), timeSteps, drop_embed, embedding_dimensions, encoder, modelType)      


  keras_model.fit(X_train_encoded, y_train_encoded, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, batch_size=32, use_multiprocessing = True, 
                            validation_data=(X_test_encoded, y_test_encoded))

  # Log the model parameters used for this run.  
  mlflow.log_param("numofActionsinWorkflow", numofActionsinWf)
  mlflow.log_param("timeSteps", timeSteps)

  #wrap it up in a pyfunc model
  wrappedModel = KerasWrapper(keras_model, encoder, decoder, bestActionCount)

  # Create a model signature using the tensor input to store in the MLflow model registry
  signature = infer_signature(X_test_encoded, wrappedModel.predict(None, X_test_encoded))
  # Let's check out how it looks
  print(signature)

  # Create an input example to store in the MLflow model registry
  input_example = np.expand_dims(X_train[17], axis=0)
  
  # The necessary dependencies are added to a conda.yaml file which is logged along with the model.
  model_env = mlflow.pyfunc.get_default_conda_env()
  # Record specific additional dependencies required by the serving model
  model_env['dependencies'][-1]['pip'] += [
    f'tensorflow=={tf.__version__}',
    f'mlflow=={mlflow.__version__}',
    f'sklearn=={sklearn.__version__}',
    f'cloudpickle=={cloudpickle.__version__}',
  ]
  
  #log the model to experiment
  #mlflow.keras.log_model(keras_model, artifact_path = runName, signature=signature, input_example=input_example, conda_env = model_env)
  
  wrapped_model_path = runName
  
  if (os.path.exists(wrapped_model_path)):
    shutil.rmtree(wrapped_model_path)
  
  #Log model as pyfunc model
  mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(runName, python_model=wrappedModel, signature=signature, input_example=input_example, conda_env = model_env)

  #return the run ID for model registration
  run_id = mlflow.active_run().info.run_id
  
  mlflow.end_run()
```

Here is the error that i receive
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue/bug which hasn't been fixed in MLFLOW. HEre is a link to it. https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/4005

Comment: Others have reported and added to the github issue. But there hasn't been any resolution in almost a year (it was first reported on Jan 21st, 2021). I remember seeing another post claiming that Deep Learning models are too BIG to pickle and therefore cannot. But then, how does one convert a TF/Keras model to a MLflow Pyfunc wrapper?